hide an li element if it has a specific hyperlink in it
I am trying to hide complete  element if it includes an hyperlink which has a title including xx.
I can hide the hyperlink with below code.
ul>li>a[title^="zz"] {
  display:none;
}

But there is empty space there since, li is still there.
This is complete line of li. When a href has a title which start with xx, I want to hide whole code in below line.
 <li><a href="https://www.example.org" title="xx-2" tabindex="0" class="fibo"><div class="fibo_label"><span>xx-2</span></div><div
> class="fibo__counter">99</div></a></li>


you may use has li:has(a[title^="xx"]) {display: none;} to target the parent li having such an anchor

Edit:
You can achieve what you are after with
li:has(a[title^="xx"]) {display: none;}

As said in the comment by Diego D, I will leave this answer in case you will need to use JS to do such a thing.
You cannot achieve what you are after with pure CSS since CSS selectors don't provide a way to select a parent element based on the attributes or content of a child element.
You can achieve the behaviour you are after with Javascript or preferably with jQuery


$(document).ready(function() {
  // Select all 'a' elements within 'li' elements whose title attribute starts with 'xx'
  $('li > a[title^="xx"]').each(function() {
    // Hide the parent 'li' of each 'a' element
    $(this).parent().hide();
  });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.example.org" title="xx-2" tabindex="0" class="fibo">
      <div class="fibo_label"><span>xx-2</span></div>
      <div> class="fibo__counter">99</div>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="https://www.example.org" title="different-title" tabindex="0" class="fibo">
      <div class="fibo_label"><span>different-title</span></div>
      <div> class="fibo__counter">99</div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>



Pure JavaScript example:


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // Select all 'a' elements within 'li' elements
  var links = document.querySelectorAll('li > a[title^="xx"]');

  // Loop through all found 'a' elements
  links.forEach(function(link) {
    // Hide the parent 'li' of each 'a' element
    link.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
  });
});
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.example.org" title="xx-2" tabindex="0" class="fibo">
      <div class="fibo_label"><span>xx-2</span></div>
      <div> class="fibo__counter">99</div>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="https://www.example.org" title="different-title" tabindex="0" class="fibo">
      <div class="fibo_label"><span>different-title</span></div>
      <div> class="fibo__counter">99</div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>



